# ASP.NET Windows authentication with wrong identity over VPN

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication, vpn

I have ASP.NET application with windows authentication. When I browse it from home over VPN (Cisco VPN Client) as a username in the windows identity I get "my-pc-name\my-pc-username" not the credentials from the AD of the server (the same that I am using to connect to the VPN) even though I fill them in the prompt for localhost authentication from the browser.
This only happens with Firefox. In the IE and Chrome after the prompt I get 401.1 Unauthorized page from IIS.

How to make IIS to use the right credentials or the problem is somewhere else?

Any ideas?

Comment: I worked around the problem like changing the username from AD username to "my-pc-name\my-pc-username" in the ASP.NET application that I am trying to log on.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the proper solution to this? My coworker and I are having the exact same problem. We tried your work around, and it solved the issue with the 401, however, it now seems that we aren't getting the proper permissions.

Comment: Hey, it was some time ago, but no, I don't remember finding a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps could solve "Error 401.2":

**Step 1:** Turn on the Windows Authentication feature

1. Click Start, type control panel in the Start Search box, and then
   click Control Panel in the Programs list.
2. Click Programs and Features, and then click Turn Windows features on
   or off.
3. Expand Internet Information Services, expand World Wide Web
   Services, and then expand Security.
4. Click to select the Windows Authentication check box, and then click
   OK.

**Step 2:** Add the Integrated Windows authentication native module in IIS Manager

1. Click Start, type Inetmgr in the Start Search box, and then click
   Inetmgr in the Programs list.
2. If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a
   confirmation, type the password, or click Continue.
3. In the Connections pane, expand the computer that is running IIS 7.0,
   expand Web Sites, and then click Default Web Site.
4. On the Default Web Site Home page, double-click Modules.
5. In the Actions pane, click Add Native Module.
6. In the Add Native Module dialog box, click to select the
   WindowsAuthenticationModule check box, and then click OK.